# How to smoothly animate relatively positioned divs filling gaps left by other divs?

Tags: jquery, css

This is a menu using relatively positioned hexagons. When I click on one of the hexagons, the other hexagons are supposed to disappear and the one clicked receives the class selected and is highlighted on the upper left on the div.

The animation is abrupt, in part because of he way the other divs disappear.

How to smoothly animate the change of position of selected divs in this case? Here's a link for the animation (note: the first three elements move smoothly).

https://codepen.io/sobrancelhas/pen/MbOggV

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $('.hexagonTile').click(function(e) {

        var items = $(this).find('.circle a');

        for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
            items[i].style.left = (50 - 35*Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
            items[i].style.top = (50 + 35*Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
        }

        e.preventDefault(); $(this).find('.circle').toggleClass('open');

        if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
            $(this).removeClass('selected', 1000);
            $(".hexagonTile").not(this).animate({
                'height': 'show',
                'width': 'show',
                'opacity': 'show'
            }, 1000);

        } else {
            $(this).addClass('selected', 1000);
            $(".hexagonTile").not(this).animate({
                'height': 'hide',
                'opacity': 'hide',
                'width': 'hide'
            }, 1000);

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please assume that you clicked on hexagon right of middle row (The 7th hexagon from top left).

The width of all hexagons but this start to decreasing from 200 to 199 to 198 ...

when their width become 140px the first row has **5** hexagon opacity so your **5th** hexagon (left of row 2) **jumps** to first row!

and all hexagons after that jumps 140px left. This jumping repeat a few times by width decreasing and cause we feel moving is not smooth.

So you must use absolute positioning to hexagons become independent of each other positions.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, but the transition of the selected item is still trembling.

Comment: Yes i see but i think it is a little batter. Please try to change some things for better performance. For example transfer current row and hide others once clicking

Comment: I change my answer.